# Ошибка при деплоя "git push heroku master"

Tags: python, selenium, discord, heroku

Написал дискорд бота на *discord.py*. Решил задеплоить его на heroku. Прописывал все команды, которые показывал сам heroku, добавил все нужные файлы, а именно "Procfile" и "requirements". Когда прописываю команду "git push heroku master", выходит ошибка -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из библиотек, помимо discord.py, использовал selenium и так что драйвер к нему *geckodriver.exe*

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не залогинились под heroku
Отправте команду

```
heroku apps
```

Если будет ошибка то нужно залогиниться, например,

```
heroku login
```

Comment: я залогинился там...

Comment: какой результат команди heroku apps?

Comment: показывается без ошибок, что я зашел

Comment: В перечне есть `yasha-new-video`?
Попробуйте запустить явно `git push heroku master -a yasha-new-video`